# convert h.264 live stream to mjpeg live stream

Tags: streaming, h.264, mjpeg, transcoding

most browsers can directly display a HTTP MJPEG Stream... while they can´t display h.264 via RTSP without the help of plugins...

I have a security cam that can only stream h.264 via RTSP so I can´t view the live video on my browser (nor iPhone etc.) and I do not want to install any APPs or Plugins...

But I have a Linux Server... I would like to retrieve the h.264 on my server and restream it in MJPEG, so I can browse to my server and see the MJPEG stream via HTTP...

After three days googling around and trying a lot with live555, ffmpeg, VLC and other tools I still did not get it running...

What is the right way to achieve my goal (with free tools like ffmpeg, live555 or whatsever needed...)?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself... using vlc it was important to use quotation marks :sout'....' which I did not know... now it works as expected..